# How can I make a string dynamic based on any number of parameters?

Tags: python, arrays

How can I make a string dynamic based on any number of parameters?

In particular this return string:

```
return '{0} {1} {2} "{3} {4} {5} {6}"'.format(params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3], params[4], params[5], params[6])
```

It needs to be able to handle between 4 and 7 parameters in between the quotes, when I added `{7}` and `params[7]` I get an `IndexError` if there were only 4 parameters for the quotes (7 total parameters).

TIA

Answer (score 1):

```
print '{0} "{1}"'.format(' '.join(params[:3]), ' '.join(params[3:]))
```

But I would advise you to not try to stick this in oneliner. Make two disctinct parts separately and then assemble then in via `.format`.
This is going to be much more readable (even variable names document your code) and easier to maintain later.

One way to do this is to use dictionary:

```
data = {
    'first_part' : ' '.join(params[:3]),
    'quoted_part': ' '.join(params[3:])
}
print '{first_part} "{quoted_part}"'.format(**data)
```

This works well if you want to print this stuff on the screen etc. Just remember, that this is not a secure way to assemble shell commands or database queries!

Comment: @SamRoberts What do you mean by being able to do it in 2 lines?

Comment: more verbose example added. I don't know what is the meanining of data in your code, but you should rather use something more descriptive that `quoted_part` etc.
Also, if answer fits you, you should accept it, so other know it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = '{} {} {} " ' + '{} '*(len(params)-3) +'"'
return str.format(*params)
```

Updated without the additional space at the end:

```
str = '{} {} {} "'  + ' '.join(['{}']*(len(params)-3)) +'"'
return str.format(*params)

>>>params=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Output

```
'1 2 3 "4 5 6 7"'
```

The `' '.join(['{}']*(len(params)-3))` creates a string of `'{}'` and the `len(params)-3` decides how many they are.

`*params` means a collection of arguments. Here it will unpack the params into a collection of arguments. `param[0]` is the first argument, `param[1]` is the second argument.... Then they will fill those `{}` with its value.

Comment: this produces an additional space before the second doublequote. Use `' '.join` to avoid it.

Comment: An explanation about what this code does and how does it work ?

Comment: Thanks, but its giving this error: zero length field name in format

Answer (score 0):

The following seems a bit simplistic but works:

```
#!/bin/python
params = [1, 2, 3]
mystr = '%s ' * len(params) % tuple(params)
```

... though it does have a trailing space.  To get rid of that you could use something a bit uglier like:

```
mystr = ('%s ' * (len(params)-1) + "%s") % tuple(params)
```

This assumes that old fashioned **%** interpolation is sufficient and that you don't need any special features provided by the *.format()* method.

Comment: I suppose I should mention that you could build a "template" string of any length less than the length of params and use a slice to supply just the desired sub-sequence of its items.  That should be obvious; and it's not clear if that would be necessary for your use-cases.